# variation of $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})- \frac{1}{1+x}$ over $(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I want to study the variation of $f(x)=(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ which is defined on $(-\infty,-1) \cup(0,+\infty)$. So,I first computed its derivative $$f'(x)= (\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})- \frac{1}{1+x}) f(x).$$  However the only way I have found to determine the sign of $f'(x)$ is to study the derivative of $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})- \frac{1}{1+x}):$ $$k(x)= \frac{-1}{x(x+1)^2}.$$
So I would like to know if there is another faster and more efficient way to study the variations of this function without going through the second derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, if $x>0$,\begin{align}\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)&=\log\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)\\&=\log(x+1)-\log x\\&=\int_x^{x+1}\frac1t\,\mathrm dt\\&>\frac1{x+1}\bigl((x+1)-x\bigr)\\&=\frac1{x+1}.\end{align}Therefore $f'(x)>0$ in $(0,\infty)$.

And, if $x<-1$,\begin{align}\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)&=\log\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)\\&=-\log\left(\frac x{x+1}\right)\\&=-\log\left(\frac{-x}{-x-1}\right)\\&=-\bigl(\log(-x)-\log(-x-1)\bigr)\\&=-\int_{-x-1}^{-x}\frac1t\,\mathrm dt\\&>-\frac1{-x-1}\\&=\frac1{x+1}.\end{align}And then the same argument as before applies.

Comment: Thank for the detailed reply. However, I dont understand why $\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{1}{t}dt>\frac{1}{x+1}((x+1)-x)$ ?

Comment: Because you always have$$\int_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm dt>(b-a)\min f,$$when $f$ is continuous and not constant.

Comment: Could you have any link or can you explaind me in details why this is true ? I would like to better understand this inequality, it's really not obvious for me

Comment: and why $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is the min int this context ?

Comment: Let $m=\min f$. Then$$\int_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm dt>\int_a^bm\,\mathrm dt=(b-a)m.$$

Comment: Because $\frac1t$ is decreasing on $[x,x+1]$, and therefore the minimum is attained when $t=x+1$.

Comment: Thanks I understood this derivation.  Now I have some trouble to see why when $x>0$ or $x<-1$ we have the same equality  $\log(1+\frac{1}{x})=\log(\frac{x+1}{x})$ . I thought we were allowed to write that when $x >0$

Comment: Because $1+\frac1x$ is *always* equal to $\frac{x+1}x$.